# How to speed up the genetic algorithm for python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function:

```
ww = get_w()

new_w = []
t = time.time()
for i in range(len(ww)):
    delta_w = r.choices(range(len(ww)), weights=rand, k=len(ww[0]))
    print(time.time()-t)
    new_w.append([])
    for x in range(len(delta_w)):
        if r.random()*100 <= mutashen_procent:
            new_w[i].append(ri(-1*10000000, 1*10000000)/10000000)
        else:
            new_w[i].append(ww[i][delta_w[x]])`
```

The ww array consists of several one-dimensional arrays.

My task is to go through these arrays and randomly take different elements with a certain chance and with a small probability create a new one in general to shuffle the arrays.

And for the sake of speed, I am ready to give up the appearance of new elements.

Comment: Can you give explicit examples of what *ww* might look like? Also, what does *ri()* do? If it's highly CPU-intensive you might find multiprocessing advantageous

Comment: Have you looked into using Numba?

Comment: @CtrlZ
ww = [[-0.7, -0.2, 0.1, 0.8],
           [-0.5, -0.9, 0.2, 0.4],
           [-0.85, 0, 0.47, 0.6]]
rand = [0.15, 0.35, 0.5]
--->
ww = [[-0.85, -0.9, 0.1, 0.4],
           [-0.5, -0.9, 0.2, 0.4],
           [-0.85, -0.2, 0.47, 0.6]]
`ri = random.randint`

@jared
Yes